# Process good records and capture only the bad records when merging to table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below requirement:

1. Read a `.csv` file with a specific pattern from AWS S3 and push it to a Snowflake table `TABLE_1`.
2. When pushing to `TABLE_1`, I have to concatenate few columns of each row of the file and check if that concatenated value is already available in `MAIN_ID` column of `TABLE_1`.
3. If already available, then update few columns else insert all columns of that row from the file to `TABLE_1` .
4. If there are any failures or bad records in the files, then the bad records should be inserted to `CUSTOM_ERROR_TABLE` while processing the other records without any failures.
5. I should try to use only one table from pushing the records from AWS S3 to Snowflake and one table to capture the records that encountered an error.
6. All this to be incorporated as a stored procedure.

**What I've done so far**:

1. Have created a TABLE_1 and STAGE to read from AWS S3 with the KEY and CREDENTAILS.
2. Created MERGE query to implement the UPDATE and INSERT functionality said above.
3. Tried INSERTing into `CUSTOM_ERROR_TABLE` when catching the exception. But this approach doesn't process the other records instead it just captures the first failed record and terminates the stored procedure.
4. Tried LOG ERRORS syntax too to capture the failures but that didn't work either.

Am I missing something here? Or if this is not feasible, kindly suggest a best alternative approach and let me try using that.

**Stored procedure**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEV_MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA_DEV.MY_STORED_PROC("ENV" VARCHAR(16777216))
            RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
            LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
            EXECUTE AS OWNER
            AS 'MY_TABLE = `${ENV}_MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA_${ENV}.TABLE_1`;
                
                MY_MERGE_QUERY = `MERGE
            INTO ${ENV}_MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA_${ENV}.TABLE_1 AS TARGET
            USING   (
                        SELECT $1 NAME, $2 GENDER, $3 DOB, $4 MARITAL_STATUS, $5 PREFERENCE,
                        UPPER(REPLACE(
                        CASE WHEN $3 IS NOT NULL THEN $3 ELSE '''' END || ''~'' || 
                        CASE WHEN $4 IS NOT NULL THEN $5 ELSE '''' END || ''~'' ||
                        CASE WHEN $5 IS NOT NULL THEN $17 ELSE '''' END, 
                        '' '',
                        ''''
                        )) AS MAIN_ID
                        FROM   @MY_STAGE ( FILE_FORMAT => ''MY_FILE_FORMAT'', PATTERN => ''.*PAT.*.txt'' ) ) AS SOURCE
            ON TARGET.MAIN_ID = SOURCE.MAIN_ID
            WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE
            SET              
                TARGET.NAME = SOURCE.NAME,
                TARGET.GENDER = SOURCE.GENDER,
                TARGET.UPDATE_DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT
                (
                    NAME,
                    GENDER,
                    DOB,
                    MARITAL_STATUS,
                    PREFERENCE,
                    MAIN_ID,
                    INSERT_DATE,
                    UPDATE_DATE
                )
                VALUES
                (
                    NAME, GENDER, DOB, MARITAL_STATUS, PREFERENCE, MAIN_ID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
                );`;
                
                try {  
                var query_result = snowflake.execute({ sqlText: MY_MERGE_QUERY });
                query_result.next();
                var rows_inserted = query_result.getColumnValue(1);
                var rows_updated = query_result.getColumnValue(2);
                
                return rows_inserted + "," + rows_updated;
                }
                catch (err)  {
                        INSERT INTO ${ENV}_MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA_${SCHEMA_ENV}.CUTOM_ERROR_TABLE (ERROR_MESSAGE, UPDATE_DATE)
                            SELECT ${err}, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() FROM SOURCE;
                        throw `Exception/Error occured in procedure MY_STORED_PROC: "${err}"`;         
                    }
            ';
```

Comment: SQL, generally, works on record sets not individual records - so there is no way to merge a record set and trap individual record errors. Either the merge as a whole succeeds or it fails. To do what you want you would need to loop through each record individually and merge it - while it would be possible to write code to do this, the performance would be substantially worse than for processing the record set in one go